# Get the row id that has selected option from dropdown - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

What I am trying to do in my project is that I have a table with two rows.

First row has 3 columns and in each td, there is a dropdown.

Second row has only 1 column.

Now, I have to fetch the id of the td which has a particular selected value from the dropdown.

What I am trying to do is this :

```
$("#R1C1,#R1C2,#R1C3,#R2C1").append($("#selectServices"));
     $(" #selectServices").on('change', function (){
        if($("#selectServices option:selected" ).text()=="Check In"){
            // need code to get td id from select dropdown with text as Check In
        }
     });
});
```

Where R1C1 stands for row 1 column 1 and so on..
selectServices is the id for my dropdown
Check In is the required option value I want from my dropdown

Comment: 1. IDs need to be unique 2. append MOVES the object. You likely want to CLONE it - please click the `<>` to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this is what you are looking for. Check the desired value on change of dropdown itself.

**HTML :**

```
<table id="table-id">
  <tr>
    <td id="#R1C1">
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="#R1C2">
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td id="#R1C3">
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="#R2C1">
      <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").on('change', function() {
      if($(this).val() == "mercedes") {
        console.log($(this).parent()[0].id)
      }
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/yk0qzd85/

Answer (score 3):

You could use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** to go up to the parent `td` then use **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to get the `id` attribute, like :

```
$("#selectServices option:selected").closest('td').attr('id');
```

Hope this helps.